# Android - SQLite create table error

Tags: android, sqlite

The error says something like (near "create": syntax error) when preparing 'create table option... create table score... I'll just post all other codes in my program so that I can ask whenever there's more problem encountered.

This is my table (in DBHelper.java):

`final static String sqlcreate=`

```
        "create table option (id integer primary key autoincrement," + 
        "volume boolean not null, vibrate boolean not null, theme text not null) " +    

        "create table score (id integer primary key autoincrement," +
        "score text not null, difficulty text not null, date date not null, );";
```

This is my DBFunction.java:

`public int addScore(String score, String difficulty){`

`ContentValues values = new ContentValues();`

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
    Date scoredate = new Date();    
    values.put("score", score);
    values.put("difficulty", difficulty);
    values.put("date", dateFormat.format(scoredate));   
    return (int) db.insert(tableScore, null, values);
}`
```

And this is my OnClick():

`if (v==btnadd){`

```
        String vol = tbtnvol.getText().toString();
        String vib = tbtnvib.getText().toString();
        String theme = themename.getText().toString();
        options.open();
        options.addOption(vol, vib, theme);
        options.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data has been added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }`
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix your query as below:

```
"create table option (id integer primary key autoincrement," + 
"volume boolean not null, vibrate boolean not null, theme text not null); " +

"create table score (id integer primary key autoincrement," +
"score text not null, difficulty text not null, date date not null);";
```

You have missed semi-colon and left an extra comma in your query

Comment: Oh, it is not included in my query, sorry.. It's suppose to be "`", the one that you type here in stackoverflow when writing codes.. I'll just fix that.. I'll try first to separate my table into different variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the two SQL statements in there with a semicolon.

```
... theme text not null); " +   <-- semi colon added here
"create table score ...
```

Answer (score 0):

your first Query without error

```
create table option (id integer primary key autoincrement,volume boolean not null, vibrate boolean not null, theme text not null)
```

second query

```
create table score (id integer primary key autoincrement," +
```

"score text not null, difficulty text not null, date date not null)

i have checked it now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

remove  , from end

```
"create table score (id integer primary key autoincrement," +
    "score text not null, difficulty text not null, date date not null, );";
```

write as follow

```
"create table score (id integer primary key autoincrement," +
    "score text not null, difficulty text not null, date date not null);";
```

yup, and also put ; at end as Graham said